tcolorbox with parbox=false AND working href links?
I am using parskip in my document and would like the contents of my tcb environments also to follow the same format. This solution suggests to use the parbox=false option, but I'm finding that it breaks hyperref hyperlinks to labels created inside those environments. The MWE is below
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{article}%{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[skip=.3\baselineskip plus 2pt\relax, parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\providecommand{\remarkname}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{rem}{\protect\remarkname}[subsection]


\usepackage[many,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tcbwrap}{mm}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn{#1}{\tcolorboxenvironment{##1}{#2}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\tcbwrap{rem}{parbox=false}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]
    {hyperref}
   

\usepackage{lipsum}  



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\newpage

    \begin{rem}[Name]\label{rem}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{rem}

    Reference to Theorem~\ref{rem}.
\end{document}

The result is that there is a warning pdfTeX warning (dest): name{rem.0.0.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one and the link in the PDF takes you to the beginning of the PDF instead of the actual tcolorbox. I suppose that the workaround would be to use the second solution to the same SE question, but I'm not familiar enough with tcolorbox to implement that with \tcbwrap.
Note: I would like the changes to the environment definitions to be minimal because changing hundreds of them in my document would be quite laborious.

why do you have hundreds of definitions rather than just hundreds of uses? isn't e.g. rem defined once in the preamble, however many times it is used in the document? are you sure your documents use latin9 encoding? pretty much any editor these days defaults to Unicode.

@cfr I meant hundreds of uses. But I just don't want to pass labels as arguments, that's why the tcbwrap method is used rather than tcolorboxenvironment.

well it is imho a bug in the tcolorbox option parbox=false. You can report that, but beside this, better do not use it and reset the parskip/parindent manually, e.g. with something similar to \AddToHook{env/rem/begin}{\parindent=0pt \parskip=\baselineskip}.

@UlrikeFischer oh that's much simpler than I expected, thanks!

@UlrikeFischer Reported here: https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/297. Thoughts appreciated

Fixed in https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/commit/6f0378f4339538d397874873d338c85c8b03c6bb and will be in next hyperref release
